# MultiResourceItemReader inside Jar doesn't read resource files

Tags: spring-batch

I created a job and archived it into a jar.

When I run it with `exec:java` it works. When I invoke it with `java -cp myjar.jar`, MultiResourceItemReader doesn't seem read my resources what fetched from ftp server.

```xml
<bean id="merge.reader.resource"
      class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader"
      scope="step">
  <property name="resources" value="file:job1/merge/fetched/*.xml" />
  ...
</bean>
```

What did I do wrong?

```
$ ls -l
mybatch.jar
job1/merge/fetched/xxxx.xml
$ java -cp mybatch.jar x.y.z.Main
```

I created a class extending `MultiResourceItemReader` and checked that file sources are set via `setResources` method and delegate via `setDelegate`.

```xml
<!--bean id="merge.reader.resource"
         class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader" scope="step"-->
<bean id="merge.reader.resource"
      class="xxx.ExtendedMultiResourceItemReader"
      scope="step">
  <property name="strict" value="true"/>
  <property name="resources" value="file:job1/merge/fetched/*.xml"/>
  <property name="delegate" ref="merge.reader.item" />
</bean>
<bean id="merge.reader.item"
      class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader">
  <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="XXX"/>
  <property name="unmarshaller" ref="merge.reader.unmarshaller"/>
</bean>
<bean id="merge.reader.unmarshaller"
      class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
  <property name="aliases" ref="merge.reader.binder"/>
  <property name="autodetectAnnotations" value="true"/>
</bean>
<util:map id="merge.reader.binder">
  <entry key="XXX" value="xxx"/>
</util:map>
```

I really don't understand why reader don't process files.

Comment: is *job1/* or *job/* the right directory name?

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci Sorry for the typo.

Comment: if so,try *file:${user.dir}/job1/merge/fetched/*.xml*.
Another question: are you sure files have been downloaded from ftp server to local dir?

Comment: you don't need to extend MultiResourceItemReader,check file presence should be done with a decider in previous step. Log is our friend when facing problems with executable jar :(